# Why is jQuery.camelCase() function not documented?

Tags: jquery, api, camelcasing

I searched the jQuery docs for "camelCase" and found nothing, which then led me on a chase for a different method name. Ultimately, I found it in the source code, but It cost me considerable time.

So I'm wondering, why isn't this method documented in the API? As I recall, it used to be...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because its outside the public API. It could be changed or removed at anytime.